# I'm trying to implement a basic shell for a class, but keep getting a seg fault. It worked before I made the getCommandAndArgs function, why not now?

Tags: c, shell, segmentation-fault

The getCommandAndArgs function is new, but the code within the function is copy-n-past of the code that was working before.  I'm trying to allow for command line arguments, and then continue to run the shell.  I know the fork and run processes could also be in another function, but I don't want to progress further until I know why the program is crashing at this point.

```
char *cmd;
char *arguments[255];
char whitechars[] = " \n\t\r";


void getCommandAndArgs(char *tokLine) {
    char *tok;
    int i=0;
    tok = tokLine;
        while(tok != NULL) {
            if(strcmp(tok, "exit")==0) { 
                    printf("Thank you for using myshell!\n");
                        exit(0); 
                }

                if(i==0) { cmd = tok; }

                arguments[i] = tok;
                tok = strtok(NULL, whitechars);
                i++;
        }
        arguments[i]=NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *line, *tok;
    int status=0;
    int i;
    pid_t pid;

    if(argc > 1) {
        line = *argv;
        tok = strtok(line, whitechars);
        tok = strtok(NULL, whitechars);

        getCommandAndArgs(tok);

        pid = fork();
                if(pid == 0) {
                        execvp(cmd, arguments);

                        //oh $h!t message
                        fprintf(stderr, "What is this: %s\n", arguments[0]);
                        exit(0);

                }
                else {
                        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
                        if(status !=0) {
                                fprintf  (stderr, "error: %s exited with status code %d\n", arguments[0], status);
                        }
                }


    }

    while((line = readline("myShell: ")) != NULL) {

        if(strcmp(line, "")==0) { 
                    continue;                
                }

        tok = strtok(line, whitechars);

        getCommandAndArgs(tok);

        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0) {
            execvp(cmd, arguments);

            //oh $h!t message
            fprintf(stderr, "What is this: %s\n", arguments[0]);
            exit(0);

        }
        else {
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            if(status !=0) {
                fprintf  (stderr, "error: %s exited with status code %d\n", arguments[0], status);
            }
        }

        free(line);
    }
    printf("\nThank you for using myshell!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first reaction when getting a segmentation fault, or any other crash, should be to run your program in a debugger. This will tell you where it happened, let you examine the call stack so you know how you ended up where you are, and also let you examine variables to help you understand the cause.

Comment: However, a probable cause is that you do not properly initialize local variables before you use them. You should be getting warnings about that, and about unused arguments as well.

Comment: char *arguments[255]; and arguments[i] = tok; without any overrun checks.. this is bound to segfault

Comment: You also have local variables and global variables named the same, which will cause problems as the global `arguments` array is modified in `getCommandAndArgs` leaving the local `arguments` array in `main` untouched.

Comment: @joachim: I didn't get any warnings from it, but initializing tok in the function stopped it from a seg fault there.  It's giving me error "error: (null) exited with status code 139" now when I run "./myshell cat myshell.c"

Comment: Probably because you have a global variable named `arguments` _and_ a local in `main` with the same name. The local variable doesn't get initialized. And lastly, you _really_ should learn to use a debugger. It will help you immensely in finding errors like this.

Comment: I removed that as well.  Is there a debugger you recommend?  I looked into gdb, but I would prefer a more user friendly debugger :)

Comment: @matthewjohnson: For the debugger: I recommand to use Eclipse with CDT and in the Eclipse contains a good graphical interface for gdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your function

```
void getCommandAndArgs(char *tokLine) {
```

there is

```
tok = strtok(tokLine, whitechars);
```

missing before the `while` loop

or

```
tok = tokLine;
```

if the `strtok` is done outside the function

Comment: This cleared up most of it, but still getting an error (see above)

Answer (score 0):

@matthew johnson You deference the tok pointer without initializing it. Mohamed KALLEL's code looks better

Comment: I added the line tok = tokLine; at the start of the getCommandAndArgs function, and that cleared up half of it.  However, when I run "./myshell cat myshell.c" I get my error "error: (null) exited with status code 139"

Comment: @Subbu this should be a  comment and not an answer

Comment: Sure ... Thanks... I am a noon here at stack overflow :)